# Constraint on required field if another field is present in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

```
create table Person(
    FName varchar(15) not null
    ,LName varchar(25) not null
    ,Address varchar(100)
    ,City varchar(30)
    ,State varchar(30)
    ,Zip varchar(10)
    ,Phone varchar(15)
    ,Email varchar(60)
    ,UserID varchar(30)
    ,Password varchar(30) not null
    ,CCtype numeric(1) check (CCType >=3 and CCType <=6)
    ,CCNumber numeric check(CCNumber >= 15 and CCNumber <=16)
    ,primary key(UserID)
    ,constraint unique_email unique(Email)
);

create table Course(
    CourseId numeric(10,0)
    ,Name varchar(100) not null
    ,Start date not null
    ,[End] date not null
    ,Description varchar(255)
    ,Price numeric(5,2)
    ,Category varchar(30)
    ,TrainerID varchar(30)
    ,primary key(CourseId)
    ,constraint date_ck check([End] > Start)
    ,foreign key(TrainerID) references Person(UserID)
    ,constraint unique_combo unique(Name, Start)
);
```

I want to create a constraint so that when CCNumber is present a valid CCType must also be present.

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: Credit card number that is only 15 digits???

Comment: Not aware of a constraint like that. What if one of the options for the CCType is "None", then it can be required...

Comment: @ganders AMEX card #s are 15-digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Person 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CCvalidity
CHECK 
(
    (CCType is null and CCNumber is null) 
    or 
    (
        (CCType >=3 and CCType <=6)
        and
        (CCNumber >= 15 and CCNumber <=16)
    )
)
```